# Compiling and linking .asm file to C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, cmake

I'm on Windows with Visual Studio 2010. I have a bunch of .cpp files and an .asm file I want to compile together.

Right now I'm doing a custom command to compile the .asm separately as follows:

```
#windows 64 bit builds need an asm file that needs to be compiled separately
if (MSVC AND CMAKE_CL_64)
  add_custom_command(TARGET MYPROJECT
                            PRE_BUILD
                            COMMAND "$ENV{VCInstallDir}/bin/x86_amd64/ml64" /c /W2 /nologo /errorReport:none 
                            /Fo${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.dir/Debug/ 
                            #/Fo"C:/MYPROJECT/Build/Main_ms100_64/MYPROJECT.dir/Debug/"
                            $CSrcDir}/masm64.asm
                            COMMENT "Building asm file")
endif()
```

This puts the .obj file in the correct place as the other obj files but it doesn't seem to be included by the linker. How do I make the linker the masm64.obj file?

As an alternate solution, I tried setting the source properties of the file to "LANGUAGE ASM" but it was still not compiling it.

Comment: The thing I always forget to do when adding .asm files is to right click on the project (not the solution) and choose 'Build Customizations' and check 'masm'.  Failing that, I spose you could go to Linker/Input and add the file to 'Additional Dependencies.'

Comment: You will either love this guy or hate him.  He has more than one hundred tutorials on this and related topics.  Go here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D    (I hope I cut and pasted it properly)

Answer (score 0):

I normally set a custom build tool on the file itself.  There is a checkbox that indcates whether the ouput participates in the build or not.  From my experience, I've found that if I have that box checked, and the assembler is outputting to the correct intermediate directory.  I've found that if I use the custom command, I have to explicity add the object file to the linker command line.